# replace does only trigger one trigger in mariadb

Tags: mysql, replace, triggers, mariadb

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE `trigger_root` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `trigger_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and the following triggers

```
DELIMITER ||

CREATE TRIGGER tit 
BEFORE INSERT ON trigger_root
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trigger_test (p) values (NEW.p);
END ||

CREATE TRIGGER tdt 
BEFORE delete ON trigger_root
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    delete from trigger_test where p=OLD.p;
END ||

DELIMITER ;
```

However if I use the following statement

```
replace into trigger_root(id,p) select id,p from trigger_root;
```

only the delete trigger is called. if i remove the delete trigger the insert trigger is called.
so it seems replace only triggers one but not both triggers
is that a general restriction or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. the insert nedds to be after rahter than before.